# Peculiar use of "wore"

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-usage

What does the word "wore" below mean (in bold)?

> As one becomes familiar, Ancient and Modern Rome, at first so
> painfully and discordantly jumbled together, are drawn apart to the
> mental vision. One sees where objects and limits **anciently wore**;
> the superstructures vanish, and you recognize the local habitation of
> so many thoughts. When this begins to happen, one feels first truly at
> ease in Rome.

*From "At Home And Abroad Or, Things And Thoughts In America and Europe" by Margaret Fuller Ossoli*

Comment: It seems to me like that's simply a typo for *were*.

Comment: @PeterShor Thank you! That's right - I should have googled before posting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a typo for "were", as one can see from [this 1860 book](https://books.google.com/books?id=c1oSAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA259&lpg=PA259&dq=%22One+sees+where+objects+and+limits+anciently+were%22&source=bl&ots=G_6e0VvO51&sig=ACfU3U1YZGNklR-ORnGVZ9HFQK7OwiQmfQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiUtr3S9JD2AhVllIkEHXZADXQQ6AF6BAgCEAM#v=onepage&q=%22One%20sees%20where%20objects%20and%20limits%20anciently%20were%22&f=false), found in Google books.